# Which way for combining of conditions is preferable for unions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, query-performance

There are some tables with some fields (on PostgreSQL):

```
Table1 {a, b, c}
Table2 {c, d, a}
Table3 {f, g, a}
```

I need to union a several queries and get `a` field. All of these queries have the same condition `CONDITION_A` and others different conditions: `CONDITION_1`, `CONDITION_2`, `CONDITION_3`

Which way for combining of conditions is preferable for unions?

1)`CONDITION_A` is embedded into each query:

```
SELECT a FROM Table1 WHERE <CONDITIONS_1> AND a.someParam=<CONDITION_A>
   UNION
SELECT a FROM Table2 WHERE <CONDITIONS_2> AND a.someParam=<CONDITION_A>
   UNION
SELECT a FROM Table3 WHERE <CONDITIONS_3> AND a.someParam=<CONDITION_A>
```

2) `CONDITION_A` is embedded after unions.

```
(SELECT a FROM Table1 WHERE <CONDITIONS_1> 
   UNION
 SELECT a FROM Table2 WHERE <CONDITIONS_2> 
   UNION
 SELECT a FROM Table3 WHERE <CONDITIONS_2> ) WHERE a.someParam=<CONDITION_A>
```

Comment: **1)CONDITION_A is embedded into each query:** is preferrable in terms of LOAD as well as efficiency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, do you really need `union`?  If you can use `union all` the query will run better because `union` incurs the overhead of removing duplicates.

Putting the conditions as close to the `from` is probably a good idea.  This gives the optimizer more opportunities to optimize the query.  For instance, each query might have indexes that include `someParam`, which can be used in the subqueries.